# How to randomly generate phrases/questions/values from a compiled assembly using reflection and save as Dataset?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, reflection

I have couple of compiled dll files which contain a simple class and having string arrays holding questions and answers with marked answer.

---

### A sample question is as under:

Which of these is the chemical element with symbol C and atomic number 6? Options: A) Coal B) Carbon * C) Chloride D) Chromium

Each assembly have multiple question banks on different topics and each question bank have several hundered questions.

---

What is intended is to generate a randomly generated questions from each assembly each question bank in specific number [say 25 from each assembly in each question bank].

Please see the image below to get the clear idea and suggest the best way to extract the questions in the same fashion.

[Required http://www.imagesup.net/dt-13138191632515.png](http://www.imagesup.net/di-13138191632515.png)

Comment: What ways have you had in mind so far? What ways have you found during your own research, and why did you deem them unsuitable? Did you try implementing any of them, and if so, what is the concrete difficulty you are facing, or what error message(s) did you get?

Comment: The idea is to keep replacing the question banks with the compiled dlls with newer questions, the current project have the question bank (i.e the question arrays) within a application class which we keep updating from time to time. however that forces us to distribute the entire application again. I want to just update the questions in DLL files without replacing my main application from time to time.

Comment: Ok. So, with your solution, what exactly is posing a problem? Have you tried concretely designing and implementing it? Which step is unclear? As for your approach, why do you want to store the questions in DLLs (if it's really just question and answer strings and an indication of which answer is correct), rather than in any data format (database file? xml? anything else?)?

Comment: It seems that your difficulty arrises from the dynamic loading of assemblies through reflection. You could take a look at MEF to solve that, but why bother? Why not distribute a data file, e.g. as XML, or even create a web service?

Comment: Yes, you guys are correct on that part, I tried with XML first, and people being extra smart with that messed up the XML file even when data saved as encoded, also when I encoded the data in XML it became slow. The database is no GO, I want this solution as a standalone exe for obvious reasons. PS... **O. R. Mapper*** I am stuck at reflection level I can see properties and methods of a assembly but do not know how to extract data value from within an array on dynamic basis i.e. randomly.

Comment: The linked question contains an image link that has 404 died, so I propose this question is deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a work around.

I am using following code

---

```
public static T Extract<T>(params T[] array) // where params can be any string array
 { 
   int index = new Random().Next(0, array.Length); 
   return (T)array.GetValue(index); 
 }
```

---

```
public static string GetQuestion()
{
  return Extract<String>(new string[] { 
      "Question 1: What is the question 1 answer? (A) it's A (B) it's B * (C) it's C (D) it's D",
      "Question 2: What is the question 2 answer? (A) it's A * (B) it's B (C) it's C (D) it's D",
      "Question 3: What is the question 3 answer? (A) it's A (B) it's B (C) it's C (D) it's D * ",
      "Question 4: What is the question 4 answer? (A) it's A (B) it's B (C) it's C * (D) it's D",
  }));
}
```

and calling this method was not so difficult using reflection.